# trying to remove all characters in a string, while loop is stuck

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove all the characters in a String in which the user specifies both the String and the character they want removed. I am only allowed to use for and while loops. When I run my program, the word doesn't print at all. I put a print statement of removeAll inside the if statement and saw that it runs infinitely. Need help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("remove all")) {
        System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
        removedLetter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < userInput.length()) {

            if (userInput.charAt(i) == removedLetter) {
                wordHolderOne = userInput.substring(0,i);
                wordHolderTwo = userInput.substring(i+1);
                removeAll = wordHolderOne + wordHolderTwo;

            }
            
            else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(removeAll);
    }
```

I also tried printing i inside the if statement. In the test case where the input word was "yummy" and I tried removing the 'm's, I saw that i would get stuck at 2 and infinitely print.

Comment: You need to increment `i` in the `if` as well as the `else`

Comment: There's nothing inside of the `if` block to progress the `while` loop. What did you expect to happen? The `while` loop is dependent on `i` being less than `userInput.length()`. So if `i` doesn't change, and `userInput.length()` doesn't change, then the loop doesn't end.

Comment: Surely this whole loop could just be: `for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length(); i++) { ... }`, forgoing the `else` entirely.

Comment: As a general rule for deciding when to use 'for' and when to use 'while', if you don't know the number of iterations (it's dependent on a condition), use 'while', if you know the number (e.g. size of list), use 'for'